# How do you get 'event date > current date - 10 days) in HiveQL?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, impala

I'm putting together a query that will get refreshed daily that needs to pull records from the last ten dates.

The tables I'm accessing have a 'xxdatetime' column  with the unix time stamp and an 'eventdate' column with the date in a yyyy-mm-dd.

In Impala, the answer was easy:

```
where eventdate > to_date(days_sub(now(), 10))
```

I used a variation of it in Hive that failed because I guess it was scanning the whole table and the tables are MASSIVE:

```
where datediff(cast(current_timestamp() as string), eventdate)=10
```

Is there a light weight way in Hive SQL to filter the xxdatetime or eventdate columns by 'today - 10 days'?

Comment: DATEDIFF(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()),ts) <= 10

Maybe this?

Answer (score 2):

Eventdate is my indexed column, date_sub is (string, days to subtract) and current_date is the current Hive yyyy mm dd.

```
    eventdate > date_sub(current_date, 5)
```

I'm not sure if this is super light weight but it works!